# Разница между инверсией управления и внедрением зависимостей

Tags: java, spring

В процессе работы с Spring Framework столкнулся с двумя понятиями *Инверсии управления IOC* и *Внедрение зависимости DI* и никак не могу уловить разницу. Вроде все просто мы используем просто `@Authowired` или если это boot то `@Repository / @Service /  @Controller` и расчитываем что Spring создаст нам экземпляры в виде Singleton или Prototype. Если написал ерунду поправте пожалуйста.

**Вопрос:** Где здесь в этой системе граница между внедрением зависимости и инверсией управления (этой же зависимостью если я все правильно понимаю). Ну вроде Spring создал экземпляры и управляет их жизненным циклом... Объясните пожалуйста как правильно понимать это разделние? IOC и DI.

Спасибо.

Comment: Понимаете латинские знаки? Тогда это может поможет Вам. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648577/what-is-the-difference-between-inversion-of-control-and-dependency-injection-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> столкнулся с двумя понятиями *Инверсии управления* (IoC) и *Внедрение зависимости* (DI) и никак не могу уловить разницу

IoC - это название принципа объектного проектирования, согласно которому управление жизненным циклом некоего компонента происходит извне этого компонента. DI - это частный случай, одна из возможных реализаций концепции Инверсии управления, применяемая, в частности, в Spring. Таким образом, *с точки зрения Spring, DI и IoC - это одно и то же*. Кажется, составители документации Spring сами с трудом понимают различия, поскольку иногда используют термины DI и IoC как синонимы. Конечно, название IoC - откровенно неудачное, поскольку порой не особо понятно, в чем заключается собственно "инверсия", а авторы всевозможных статей и классификаций только добавляют неопределенности, относя к приемам IoC и порождающие паттерны, и DI-фреймворки, и JNDI.

Answer (score 1):

Простое объяснение (как я в свое время понял).

**IOC** - принцип проектирования. Когда один компонент может зависеть от интерфейса какого-то другого компонента, но не от его реализации. У этого принципа есть 2 вида шаблонов:

**DI** - шаблон, когда мы указываем в интерфейсе нашего компонента (через конструктор или сеттер), от чего тот зависит.

Также есть **DL (Dependency Lookup)** - в данном случае нам передают только  `ApplicationContext`, и мы сами посредством `ApplicationContext.getBean(...)` получаем нужные зависимости. При этом мы не указываем в интерфейсе, что конкретно будем получать.