# Инверсия зависимости на примере

Tags: java, dependency-injection, зависимости

В книге "Чистый код" всё время говорится про то, что инверсия зависимостей - это замечательная вещь. Наверно, эта правда ввиду профессионализма и опыта автора, но я так и понял, как это можно "ссылаться только на абстракции, не указывая конкретных их реализаций".

Представлю свой ход мыслей, как я пытался это понять, начав с жестко связанного кода. В приведённом ниже Java-коде (окружение методом опущено) `Realization` - одна из реализаций `ISomeInterface`:

```
ISomeInterface example = new Realization();
```

Здесь переменная переменная имеет тип `ISomeInterface`, но класс `Realization`-то мы должны в явном виде импортировать в файл!

Далее, я знаю, что фреймворк Spring даёт нам контекст, из которого можно получить конкретные экземпляры классов (внедрение зависимостей). Уже лучше, чем пример выше, но имя бина-то мы в Java-коде указать всё равно должны! Получается, что тут ссылка на конкретную реализацию есть, но нет прямого импорта класса в файл.

Ну и плюс не понятно, что делать, когда нет фреймворка типа Spring (тем более что на данный момент мой основной язык - TypeScript). Так что в этом вопросе я прошу показать пример, как это так можно ссылаться на абстракции не импортируя в модуль её реализацию.

---

- С Ответами на вопрос [Разница между инверсией управления и внедрением зависимостей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/713050/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) ознакомился;
- Если минусуете вопрос - пишите за что, чтобы я Вас в будущем не раздражал правильно заданными (в соответствие со своими представлениями) вопросами

Comment: Пусть у вас есть класс `MyClass` в котором вы делаете `ISomeInterface example = new Realization();`. Создайте в этом классе конструктор (или добавьте в существующий переменную `ISomeInterface`), который принимает `ISomeInterface example` и проставляйте нужную реализацию при создании `MyClass`. И теперь `MyClass` не будет зависеть от `Realization`, а будет зависеть от абстракции `ISomeInterface`

Comment: в java из коробки есть нечто похожее на di в общем понимании, называется ServiceLoader https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: вы правы, потому как создание объектов - одна из наибольших проблем ООП. инверсия управления - попытка решить эту проблему, переложив обязанности по созданию экземпляров классов на контейнер. так делает спринг, EJB  и им подобные. но эти решения более высокоуровневые. я бы для начала рекомендовал изучить порождающие паттерны, которые также направлены на решение этой проблемы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все сводится к тому, что вы должны по максимуму использовать интерфейсы а не конкретную реализацию. Для любого вашего класса выполняющего какие-либо действия над сущностью вы пишите интерфейс, например:

```
 public interface PersonService{
    ...
    Person getPerson(Long id);
    ...
 }
```

Все остальные классы ничего не знают о реализации данного метода. Они у себя внутри используют только метод `getPersons(Long id)`. Соответственно они ничего не знают о реализации данного метода кроме того, что они должны передать ему на вход и что он возвращает. Вы не должны в других классах использовать специфические методы реализации, вы используете только те методы, которые есть в интерфейсе.

Таким образом у вас уменьшается связанность классов. Речь идет о том, что сам класс, например `PersonControllerImpl` никак не должен изменится если вы поменяете внутреннюю реализацию метода в сервисе или сделаете другую реализацию интерфейса сервиса.

Например

```
public class PersonControllerImpl{

    private PersonService service;

    PersonControllerImpl(PersonService service){
        this.service = service;
    }

    Person getPerson(Long id){
        service.getPerson(id); 
    }
}
```

Ваш контроллер ничего не знает о реализации сервиса.
Конечно будет какой-то метод, который сделает `new PersonServiceImpl()` и передаст его на вход в контроллер, но сам контроллер от реализации никак не зависит. Например:

```
class PersonsContainer{

    private PersonService personService;
    private PersonController personController;

    PersonsContainer(){
        personService = new PersonServiceImpl();
        personController = new PersonControllerImpl( personService );
    }

}
```

При таком подходе все что вам нужно для замены класса реализации сервиса, это поменять одну строчку в классе контейнера.

Spring при запуске тоже создает все инстансы конкретных сущностей, и когда вы внедряете зависимость по интерфейсу, он находит его имплементацию, если он ее не найдет он просто не запустится. Spring вынес обязанность создания объектов  и ряд других задач в свои классы, которые в совокупности назвал контейнером.

**Что это дает**:

- чтоб при изменении одного класса не приходилось по цепочке менять половину
  программы;
- возможность повторного применения классов в других
  проектах.